# how to show the grouping the array of objects using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the array of object but I don't know how to group by the `id` as order. I want to show it numerical order like 1,2,3 using ng-repeat

```
$scope.arrayofobject=[{name:"testMachne","id":1},{name:"testComputer","id":2},{name:"testCalc","id":3},{name:"testMac","id":2},{name:"testMachne","id":3},{name:"testMachne","id":1}]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `orderBy` filter:

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
     $scope.arrayofobject=[{name:"testMachne","id":1},{name:"testComputer","id":2},{name:"testCalc","id":3},{name:"testMac","id":2},{name:"testMachne","id":3},{name:"testMachne","id":1}];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
   
    <div ng-repeat="json in arrayofobject | orderBy:'id' " ng-if='json.id !== 1'>
       {{json.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help.if i want to show the id 2 as in first position and 3 as second positon and so on.what could i do for this

Comment: you can use a condition in `ng-repeat` . Check my updated answer